Is "be" at the end of a comparative structure incorrect?

Overall, females of all age groups, except for those aged 75, were more likely to meet this recommended fruit and vegetable intake than males were.

Grammarly suggested that I remove were at the end of the above sentence. Why? I thought it's optional and that including it makes the sentence clearer and more formal. Am I missing something?

As an aside… except for those aged 75 and over … If you leave "those aged 75" the reader might think think that women aged 80 met the recommended quantity of fresh fruit and vegetables.

Putting were (BE) at the end of the comparison phrase headed by than is how many people would speak such comparisons, but when writing the tendency is to eliminate unnecessary words during the editing and "polishing" phase, and so in written works BE would appear less often in that position.  Compare: That car costs a lot more than this one does.  A perfectly idiomatic conversational utterance which would be polished to "That car is much more expensive than this one."

Sometimes you need a "be" word to resolve a possible ambiguity:

Old men are more likely to date young women than old women are.

This clearly is comparing who old men and old women date.
But without "are" it can, and probably would, be interpreted as comparing who old men are likely to date.
This ambiguity doesn't exist in your example, so "were" is optional and would often be omitted because it's unnecessary. Grammarly's recommendation is reasonable.

Fixed, it was an editing mistake


... females ... were more likely to meet this recommended ... intake than males were

Both versions are fine.
The OP’s version takes than as a conjunction:

... than males were

Grammarly takes than as a preposition:

... than males

M+W gives examples:
As a conjunction

older than I am

As a preposition

you are older than me

